# Is it all right to see thousands of "Python has shoutdown" in apache log?

Tags: apache-2.4, django, mod-wsgi

As we can see in the picture, thounds of initial&delete info appeared in logs.
[image]
I don't know what a good `Django` web site should be, but keep fork&delete seems abnormal and waste resources.

Comment: it's just an information level message. If you don't want to see it, reduce the log level.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, I know it as info level, but fork a new interpreter for every request is the "right" way to config mod_wsgi?